# which is faster moving image on canvas or moving whole canvas

Tags: performance, canvas, html5-canvas

Lets say i am making a game in which there is background that is dynamic. Now in a setup where i am using multiple canvas, so one canvas dedicated for background as it doesn't need to update as often, Also Map is not infinite it's big but not that big.

So in should i move redraw the map at every move. 
Or move the whole canvas which then would act like a layer.

Any ideas?

Will use css to clip map to size of game.

While it's true i have not tried anything but that is because i dont know what to try. I'd make both but wont know which one is working. Basically i am clueless in bench marking sector.

http://jsperf.com/translate-vs-background-position

Comment: It might change a lot from a brower or device to another. maybe this is a mission for our friend jsperf.

Comment: i did js perf and while i was at it i discovered which i used to believe was false...using top and left is faster? thank transform translate..WHY? 
http://jsperf.com/translate-vs-background-position

Comment: my jsperf works only in chrome